# Add object array to setState

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I'm trying to add an object array in the state series. With this code the useEffect function get stuck in an infinite loop. How can I solve this? Without adding the series const as parameter I get the error about a missing dependency and the code will only run on startup.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const LineChart = () => {
  const [series, setSeries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = "http://localhost:4000";

    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {

        fetch(url, {
          method: "GET",
        })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            let chartData = data.testRunSummaries
              .map(function (testrun) {
                return {
                  duration: testrun.endTime - testrun.startTime,
                  label: testrun.testSetName + "#" + testrun.userFacingId,
                  testrun: testrun.testRunId,
                  status: testrun.status,
                };
              });
            setSeries(chartData, ...series);
            console.log(series);

          });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [series]);

  return (
   ...
  );
};

export default LineChart;
```

Answer (score 0):

`series` is in your `useEffect` dependency array. And your `useEffect` is changing `series`. So obviously you'll be stuck in a infinite loop.

You don't need your `series` to be set as a dependency for `useEffect`.
As your `useEffect` will only be trigger once on mount, you can just have

```js
setSeries(chartData);
```

And if you *really* need to have former values of `series`, you should use

```js
setSeries(series => [...chartData, ...series]);
```

Moreover, seeing your

```js
setSeries(chartData, ...series);
console.log(series);
```

Let me remind you that `setState` is **async** there is no way this will log your updated state :)